# Sharing context with a nested component, getting UserContext is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to share a *service* of some sort to a component that is nested inside another, but I'm getting an undefined error.

> 'UserContext' is not defined  no-undef

This is my App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, {createContext} from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import TopPanel from "./components/topPanel/TopPanel";
import UserCtx from "./services/UserCtx";

function App() {

    const UserContext = createContext({});

    return (
        <Router>
            <UserContext.Provider value={new UserCtx()}>
                <TopPanel/>
            </UserContext.Provider>
            <Routes>
                ...
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Inside of the `TopPanel` component, there is a `Login` component, which should consume the context:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";

function Login() {

    const userCtx = useContext(UserContext);

    ...
}

export default Login;
```

But it's apparently not getting passed on. What am I doing wrong please? It doesn't even look like it's passed on to the 1st level component.

Don't think it's relevant, but here's the context object:

```
import React from "react";

class UserCtx {

    isLoggedIn;
    token;

    constructor() {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }

    logIn = (token) => {
       console.log("LOGGING IN!");
       this.isLoggedIn = true;
       this.token = token;
    }
}

export default UserCtx;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of the context should be outside of the component, this line `const UserContext = createContext({});` should be outside of `App` component, and it should be export it:

```js
export const UserContext = createContext({});
```

Make sure inside `Login`  you import `UserContext` at the top, before doing what you have there:

```js
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";
import {UserContext} from "../../App"; // use the correct path

function Login() {

    const userCtx = useContext(UserContext);

    ...
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of `UserContext` object as an outside box that can be mounted to any other objects(components) in the tree structure objects of React.
You should declare the context object outside your `App` component.